# Связь разных полей с разными таблицами sql

Tags: mysql, связи

Есть 3 таблицы (упрощены для промера)

1 images

```
id | автор
```

2 authors

```
id | имя_автора
```

3 studio

```
id | имя_студии
```

у фото автором может быть или мужик из таблицы "authors", или студия из таблицы "studio".
Попытка 1:
Нам бы привязать колонку "автор" к 2-м таблицам сразу (authors и studio)
Результат:
Технически невозможно

Попытка 2:
Создать представление authors + studio и уже его привязать к колонке автор.
Результат:
Технически невозможно делать связи с представлениями

Попытка 3:
Добавить связывающую таблицу

```
image_id | в_какой_таблице_автор | автор_id
1        | studio                | 126
```

Результат:
В колонке "в_какой_таблице_автор" может быть разные таблицы, как их связать с этими таблицами? (аля  foreign key)

Вообще, разве редкая задача привязать несколько таблиц к одному полю, с потребностью целостности данных БД? как это сделать?

Comment: Задача вполне себе частая - решить проблему, возникшую из-за разделения места хранения одной сущности на две таблицы. Обычно решается изменением схемы БД. Впрочем, бывает, что схема правильная - но Вы о предметной области не сказали ничего, а на основании только показанных данных считать схему правильной не получается.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    author_id INT, 
    studio_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (studio_id) REFERENCES studio (id),
    CHECK ((author_id IS NULL + studio_id IS NULL) = 1)
);
```

Два поля для связывания. Из них только одно содержит значение.